# Version para ordenador con un tamaño de fuente mas grande que movil

Tags: html5, responsive, mediaqueries

Hola a todos tengo un pequeño problema, tengo un blog y hace tiempo que no lo actualizaba, asi que me tome la molestia de hacerle unos cambios, el problema es que al ver la version para ordenador desde un celular, el tamaño de fuente del blog crece demasiado, más que el móvil, cosa que no debe ser.[image: Version para móvil] [image: Version para ordenador desde un móvil]
La primera imagen es version movil y la segunda es version para ordenadores desde un celular. Este es la meta viewport que uso en blogger `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"/>` y esta es la media query que uso para el tamaño de letra `@media (max-width: 1024px){ .post-body h4,  #HTML3 p, .post-body, #Profile1 ul > li, .post-footer-line{ font-size: 18px; }} @media (max-width: 360px){ .post-body h4, #HTML3 p, .post body, #Profile1 ul > li, .post-footer-line{ font-size: 15px; }}` Ahora, he probado usar un parecido media query con XAMPP y el problema no sucede, aca les dejo las imagenes[image: Version movil][image: version para ordenadores desde movil] Como pueden ver la primera foto es version movil y la segunda, version para ordenadores desde un celular, y el meta viewport es el mismo que uso en blogger
, el media query solo cambia de selector `@media (max-width: 1024px){ p{ font-size: 18px}} @media (max-width: 360px){ p { font-size: 15px }}` Les dejo el enlace del blog por si desean revisarlo desde movil y luego ver su version en ordenador que crece mucho su letra nutricionysaludpersonal.blogspot.com . Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que está pregunta pudo resultar confusa para algunos o tonta para otros, si alguien más tiene este mismo problema que tuve, lo resolví añadiendo un reset css a los estilos de blogger, agregando todo este css de esta página https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css , logré resolver el problema